# Python for loop inside for loop/

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to find two numbers in a list which are divisible by each other. I have managed to do this by placing two for loops that loop over the same list to compare numbers until a pair is found.

### My Question:

Is it possible to easily compress this code to one or two lines using a conditional statement?

```
def FindDivisible(j):
    for i in j:
        for m in j:
            if int(i) % int(m) == 0 and int(i) != int(m):
                return([int(i),int(m)])
```

*I do understand that this would not be very pythonic at all. I do however want to know if it is possible and what would be a good way for going about this.*

Comment: I think you want list comprehension. With comprehension you could this in a line or two

Comment: Your code is not properly indented. That aside, your current solution only returns the first pair of numbers that are found. For example, if the input were `j = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, your code would return `[4, 2]`. Is this what you want? What about the other pairs?

Comment: List comprehension won't solve this... To OP: why would you want to compress this into "one or two lines"? Less code is not better code. Readable code is better code, and bar poorly named variables, this code is readable.

Comment: Looks like a homework not well planned. Give it some more effort.

Comment: @andyhasit, I think you are underestimating list comprehension

Comment: @jtagle yes you can do it (see John1024's answer) but code becomes unreadable, and far less efficient, so I don't know why you'd want to. Depends what we mean by "solve". In one sense list comprehension could "solve" a 1000 problems it's not really intended to solve :-)

Comment: @dmitryro - This is not homework. Its for one of the Advent of code 2017 problems I am doing for fun.

Comment: @andyhasit I fixed the indentation! Sorry about that. Also, I understand less is not allways better, but I was just wondering if it could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one-liner will get all divisible combinations of the elements in iterable `j`:

```
[([int(i),int(m)]) for m in j for i in j if int(i) % int(m) == 0 and int(i) != int(m)]
```

The above is just your code translated into a *list comprehension*.  One difference is that this will find all combinations while your original looping code will return just the first successful combination.  If you want to exit after the first combination, then the explicit looping is the right choice.

For example:

```
>>> j=range(2,5)
>>> [([int(i),int(m)]) for m in j for i in j if int(i) % int(m) == 0 and int(i) != int(m)]
[[4, 2]]
```

Comment: The OP specified UNTIL a pair is found, this returns all. Of course you could slice the first one off. Still not sure why the OP is asking for this in first place as list comprehension makes it muddy as.

Comment: @andyhasit I find the list comprehension clearer but I understand that, based on each individual's prior experience, others may view it differently.    Also, you are right about the list comprehension approach finding all pairs, not just the first.  That is stated in the answer.

Comment: This is quite cool! I like this alot, even though it returns every combination. I might use this and just have other functions use only the information they need! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> You can probably use **itertools.product**

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Example as

```
for var1, var2 in itertools.product(xrange(min1, max1, step1), xrange(min2, max2, step2)):
    # stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

let use [itertool combinaison](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)  and filter

in 2 lines :

```
from itertools import combinations
alist =[(x,y) if  (x%y==0 or y%x==0 and x!=y ) else None for x,y in combinations(l, 2)]
L = list(filter(None, alist))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product`. Note that it is simpler to map `int` over the original input list once, rather than constantly converting individual elements.

```
from itertools import product
def find_divisible(j):
    return [(i, m) for (i, m) in product(map(int, j), repeat=2) 
             if i % m == 0 and i != m]
```